# C++ arguments comparison

Tags: c++, string, parameters, comparison

Hello I am trying to read some arguments and process them but when i try to read arguments via if else ladder a problem occurs

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
cout << argv[1] << endl;
if (argv[1] == "process")
    cout << "yes" << endl;
else
    cout << "no" << endl;
}
```

This code outputs:

> process
>
> no

Do you know why the output is **no** instead of **yes**?

*By the way I tried to convert either one of them to a string and compared it with another surprisingly it worked, even though I couldn't figure out why.*

Comment: Because you compared 2 pointers and not 2 strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv[1]` is a pointer, actually a `char *` (see the definition `char *argv[]`), and in your code `"process"` (which is a `const char []`) also decays to a `const char *`, so you are basically comparing two `char *`.

Since `char *` are simply pointers, then you are comparing addresses, not "string", and obviously `argv[1]` and `"process"` are not stored at the same address.

If you convert one of the two to `std::string`, then you are comparing a `std::string` and `char *` (or `const char *`), and `std::string` has an overloaded `operator==` for `char *` so it works.

You could compare "C strings" (aka `char` arrays) using `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

Answer (score 2):

`argv[1] == "process"` compares pointers. Use `strcmp`to compare the strings behind the pointers:

```
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
cout << argv[1] << endl;
if (strcmp(argv[1],"process")==0)
    cout << "yes" << endl;
else
    cout << "no" << endl;
}
```